# multi field collections

Tags: drupal, drupal-field-collection

I have three different types of field collections: for text, for photo and for video.
How to make that when creating new node could add these fields in any order?
Please, tell the direction for searching.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've made new node type and added three field collections with unlimited number of values.
First field collection contains text field, second - image field, third - video field.
So I want to make that when creating new node could add these fields in any order.
For example I want to create node with fields: photo, text, photo, photo, text, video etc.

Comment: solved by Paragraphs module